# How to process natural language query into solr understandable query

Tags: solr, lucene, nlp

**What i am doing and what i did so far:**
i'm developing an question and answering system using Solr,i took product reviews as my data-set(contains product id and its reviews from different users) which is in json format.i have performed indexing on my data-set and successfully got the response of indexed data.

**Requirements:**
In my Q/A system i will provide query in Natural language for example, "why should i buy X(product name)" and my Q/A should be capable of recognizing the words in reviews like "its ease to use, flexible product" and it should frame its answer depending on those words.

I would like to know the following

- How can i process natural language query into solr executable query,
- How can i prepare my answer to the query,
- What kind of nlp models should i use,
- How should i train my Q/A system
  and any other information which can help me to achieve the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nowhere near Solr yet. You have to go back and look for the actual NLP (Natural Language Processing) system. If it uses Solr (or OpenNLP that integrates with Solr) - great. If not, you have to invent this bridge, it does not just come with Solr, as this is still a cutting edge of research.